# Will setting user shell to nologin prevent them from accessing SFTP?

Tags: shell, security, sftp, nologin

I have a user that has their shell set to nologin, or actually a different binary "noshell" provided by cPanel.

whatever the case, I want to know if setting their shell this way is enough to prevent them from accessing the server and reaching its files.

when I log in with their key to SFTP I receive an error telling me `unexpected end of file`, but I am not entirely sure if that would be enough.

Additionally, how do I explicitly deny this user from using SFTP?

Thanks

Comment: I put my untrusted users (students!) in a group, set their shells to `/bin/false`, and then set up the internal-sftp engine in SSH so that it chroots them and sets a stricter default umask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that with OpenSSH_7.2p2 (On Ubunutu), setting user shell to `/usr/sbin/nologin` disables sftp.